# odd one out pattern

Tags: riddle

[image]

Which of the above images is the odd one out?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A: the only one with a non-connected inverse
B: the only one with less vertical than horizontal matches
C: the only one with no matches in the lower half
D: the only one with a non-prime number of matches
E: the only one which cannot be formed into a valid digit with moving at most two matches while staying inside the same 7-segment area

Answer (score 6):

A is the odd one out, because it is the only configuration of matches that can be made into the letter it's labelled with by adding a single match.

B is the odd one out, because it's the only one that includes "all three" horizontal matches.

C is the odd one out, because it's the only one that doesn't form a letter.

D is the odd one out, because it's the only one for which the number of matches isn't prime.

E is the odd one out, because it's the only one that forms a number in both Arabic (7) and Roman (L) numerals.

Comment: (Or, in other words: VTC as too broad.)

Comment: ah, you ninja'd me.

Comment: Yours are more interesting than mine.

Comment: let's agree that both our solutions are really nice :)

Answer (score 1):

> E. All others have a middle match.

Answer (score -1):

> C. Simple : All others form a letter.

Comment: For the sake of the puzzle - option C still forms a letter 'L' if you look at it sideways...

Comment: C also forms a letter - G - if you look at the "negative matches".